# Can Fastlane be used with Capacitor?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor, fastlane

Im using Ionic version 6.18.1 with Vue and I'd like to use FastLane. The docs talk about a platforms folder, but with Capacitor there is no platforms folder. Does that mean I need to use Cordova instead? I couldn't find any documentation on setting this up so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is are two separate platform folders, on called ios and one called android

Comment: You should be able to use it. Its just a cli tool. The same instructions in the Fastlane docs should still apply for Capacitor. Just make sure you're using it against your ios and android folders.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Fastlane with an Ionic/Capacitor project. You need to implement different lanes per platform in your `Fastfile` and specify the platform while calling fastlane.

Because your ionic project should contain a subfolder for each platform (`./ios` and `./android`), it also means that paths in your `Fastfile` must point to the correct location.

Here is an example of a `fastlane/Fastfile`:

```
platform :iOS do
    ios_dir = File.expand_path('../ios')

    lane :test do
        run_tests(
            workspace: File.join(ios_dir, "App/App.xcworkspace")
        )
    end
end

platform :android do
    android_dir = File.expand_path('../android')

    lane :test do
        gradle(task: "test")
    end
end
```

Then you can call your lane as follows:

```
$ fastlane ios test
$ fastlane android test
```

Comment: I will give it a try, thanks